# CakePHP / Croogo Login Issue

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am trying to implement Users loggin in on the homepage of the site via simple login form. I have a simple Form created for User with username and password fields created with action of `/users/login`. `users_controller/login` function is very simple:

```
$this->set('title_for_layout', __('Log in', true));

    if (!empty($this->data)) {  

            if (!$this->Auth->login($this->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Login Invalid.', true));
                $this->redirect("/");
            } else {
                $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
            }
        }
```

This WORKS when logging in with an admin user. However, if I try to login with a registered user it fails. I tried changing the `Auth->loginAction` to `/users/promoted` and did not see any results except not being able to access `/admin/` to login, which is fine since admins could just login via the homepage as well...Very stumped at this point and help is greatly appreciated!

Thank you,

Michael

Comment: Also, when I submit the login for I do receive an HTTP 302 error...

Comment: UPDATE: If i set the password field to be userPassword and Security::hash it in the login function I CAN login via the front end with any user EXCEPT and Admin Role! The admin roles CAN however login via /admin...Also, strangely enough, when a registered user logs in, a Flash message shows "Login Failed. Invalid Username or Password"...Seems like some sort of acl permissions issue but i can not figure out where.

Comment: The Flash message probably makes sense, if the login form page doesn't have the ability to output a flash message, the flash message will be saved until the first page where it can be displayed.

Comment: Furthermore, if you use AuthComponent you can have an empty login function, because AuthComponent intercepts the request and tries to login the user. If you want any logic executed after login you can define this in the login-action in the users_controller. Can you retry with an empty login function?

Comment: Thank you for the comments. Similar issue with blank login function. I can login successfully with an admin user, but registered user says "Login Failed"...

Comment: After login with admin can you go to `/admin/access_rights/authorize` or `/admin/access_rights/build_acl`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was an issue directly related to Croogo. Under Users->Permissions, for some reason the registered role was set to NOT allow Users/Login!